# Automatically check which of your ubuntu packages are available in other distributions

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, fedora

I am considering to switch from ubuntu to either arch linux or fedora. Now I want to check if the programs I use are available in those distros and in which repository (extra, AUR,...). Sure I can list my installed packages by `apt-list --installed | less` (or maybe better `apt-mark showmanual`) and then check the interesting packages manually from https://www.archlinux.org/packages or https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/. However is there more automatic way to do this?

Comment: No. There is not. The package naming is not always consistent and this was not quite priority to anyone (how frequently one needs to know that? Once, twice for a lifetime?). And what if the package is not there? Just package it for yourself or for other users of your new distribution. This is how opensource work.